# Googlecast doesn't show Use Local Network dialogue

Tags: ios, xcode, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I'm using Googlecast for a few years now on my iOS radio-app. When migrating to Xcode 17.0 something broke within my implementation. When pressing the Googlecast button for the first time a Use Local Network dialogue should be shown, but it isn't shown anymore.

Pressing the Googlecast button in my app gives the following:

```
GCKClearcutLogger.m:250: -[GCKClearcutLogger logEvent:fromSource:] - logging an event from source: 67
```

But nothing happens.

I set the following in info.plist:

[image]

Can someone help my out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading to google-cast-sdk-no-bluetooth 4.7.0 helped.